# How can I crawl only a particular domain using Python?

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I need to start with a domain and extract all links from the site, then continue on and extract the links from those links. However, I am only supposed to traverse the links that are part of the given domain. I'm using BeautifulSoup. The only way I can think to do this is to test whether the href is in the form href='www.someotherdomain.com' or of the form href = 'page1/page2'. The former would indicate that the link points to a new domain and the latter would indicate that the link points to a page within the same domain.

So I've created a function called has_domain to check to see if the link has its own domain already. The code looks like this:

```
def has_domain(url):
    if 'www.' in url:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

The problem is, not every link outside the seed domain starts with 'www.' Is there an easier way to check to see if a link points to a new domain?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What cod have you tried so far? Showing what you've tried will help us to help you and also show that you've put some effort into it.

Comment: Thanks for the response Richard. I hope my edits have showed what I've tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can use urlparse to grab the hostname and then check if it's in a list or compare it directly to a string.

Here's an example of comparing it to a list of domains, notice it treats the "www" variation as a different domain name.

```
from urlparse import urlparse

url_list = ["example.com", "www.example.com"]

def has_domain(url):
    p = urlparse(url)
    if p.hostname in url_list:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print has_domain("http://www.example.com")
```